# given wsdl file, convert into example

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

Is there any open tools/websites that if you been given a soap(wsdl) file, it can generate you some examples?

I am new to wsdl, even I've been given the api file, I don't really know how to interoperate the expect result I am going to receive

Comment: for what language/toolstack?

Comment: Try [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/) is highly recommended, as it will list all the methods in the wsdl file automatically, and will give you an option to execute the wsdl file to see the results in real time. Its also free to use.

This should give you a good start after you install SoapUI - [Your First SoapUI Project](http://www.soapui.org/Getting-Started/your-first-soapui-project.html)